# Are there any possible impacts of using LVM snapshots

Tags: linux, mysql, lvm

I am trying to design a MySQL database backup and recovery policy (Linux OS) for my company. I am looking at the LVM snapshot as a full backup solution plus binary logs rotation as an incremental.

My environment is as following:

- XenServer 5.6 connected to HP SAN using iSCISI interface
- VMs are running under CentOS or RedHat with LVM installed

What I am wondering is what kind of potential impact should I expect of using LVM snapshots? I have heard that people are using LVM for/as MySQL full backup solution but on the other hand I have heard about some issues such as I/O or CPU overheads.

Any comments will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

LVM snapshots have a huge negative impact on I/O performance. A better way to backup mysql is to replicate to a slave. When you need to perform a backup stop replication, do the backup, and then restart replication.